# How do I use the Unix tar command with an implicit filepath?

Tags: tar

I am using the `tar -xvf` command and it is taking the explicit path. However, the path is full.
Example:

```
tar -xvf 13.2.tar
```

It is taking the path of `/mnt` folder. The `/` folder is full.

How can I tar the file with the implicit path?

Comment: You should clearly elaborate on what exactly is going on, as your current way of asking the question makes even the most sophisticated crystal ball seem slightly hazy.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between using canonical (aka explicit) and relative (what you're probably calling implicit) is whether you use a `/` at the beginning.

For example, if the current working directory is `/usr/home/bob`, the following commands have exactly the same effect

```
tar -xvf foo.tar *
tar -xvf ./foo.tar *
tar -xvf ./foo.tar ./*
tar -xvf /usr/home/bob/foo.tar *
tar -xvf /usr/home/bob/foo.tar ./*
tar -xvf /usr/home/bob/foo.tar /usr/home/bob/*
```

But I suspect that this isn't really your question.  It seems more like you need to determine the disk usage, and locate a directory that's not full.  This can be done with the `df` command.

```
df -k # space on disk in kilobytes
df -m # as above, but in meg
df -g # as above, but in gig
```

And you can use `mount` to show you what file systems are mounted at what devices.

Answer (score 2):

Usually `tar` needs the `--absolute-names` or `--absolute-paths` option to retain the root `'/'` part while creating an archive. Even if you force it in that way, the extract skips the leading `'/'` too.

---

However, if you have an archive with the leading `'/'` and you tar does not skip it while extracting, NoahD's answer should work in this form,

```
pax -r -s ',/mnt,/new/path,' -v -f 13.2.tar
```

I think `pax` does not handle compressed files, so you would need to pipe after decompress into `pax`.
That would go like this (assuming you have a gzipped archive)

```
gunzip -c 13.2.tar.gz | pax -r -s ',/mnt,/new/path,' -v
```

I found [this wiki page](http://bash-hackers.org/wiki/doku.php/howto/pax) on Google just now.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [pax](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pax) will do the trick

pax -r -s,/mnt,/gooddir, -f 13.2.tar

It should let you substitute in a new root directory.

Answer (score 0):

To create a tar file with a relative path,

```
cd /parent/of/dir/to/tar
tar cvf subdir.tar subdir
```

To unpack a tar into a specific directory other than the current working directory, use the -C (uppercase C) switch.

If you want to untar a file with absolute pathnames in it to a point other than root, you might need to mess about with `chroot(1)`.